# want to input txt file instead of sinlge input value

Tags: python, base64

I want to pass list of input parameters instead single input at raw row. Please suggest.

```
import hashlib 
import hmac
import base64
import os

key = bytes("BF04AA6B-E243-4D35-A32B-AD82B4220905","ascii")
raw = bytes("5207089087__540500390673_","ascii")

hashed = hmac.new(key, raw, hashlib.sha256)
print(base64.b64encode(hashed.digest()).decode())
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a function which accepts a `key` and a list of `raw` values and then iterates on those:

```
def multi_hash(key, raws):
    for raw in raws:
        hashed = hmac.new(key, raw, hashlib.sha256)
        print(base64.b64encode(hashed.digest()).decode())
```